# In MVC View, I need to pass value from within the model to the controller from a KendoUI Widget

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

The code below works. The controller receives the value "Test Value" when the Upload widget is executed.

However, I have a key value from the model that is displayed within this view that I need to send instead of the hardcoded text.

Note. This is a custom template within a grid popup editor.

Widget
    ViewBag.Title = "Test Value";

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
.Name("files")
.TemplateId("fileTemplate")
.Async
(a => a
  .Save("Save", "OpenRecords"), new { MyRequest = ViewBag.Title })
.AutoUpload(true))
)
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string MyRequest)
    {
        // The Name of the Upload component is "files"

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Some browsers send file names with full path.
                // We are only interested in the file name.

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
                // The files are not actually saved in this demo
                 file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                 ViewBag.FileName = fileName;
                 //return Content(physicalPath);

            }

        }

        // Return an empty string to signify success
        return Content("");


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Upload' event within the control.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
.Name("files")
.TemplateId("fileTemplate")
.Events(e => e.Upload("onFileUpload"))
.Async(a => a.Save("Save", "Attachment").AutoUpload(true)))
```

The in your javascript, define the method onFileUpload:

```
var onFileUpload = function (e) {
  e.data = { MyRequest : ViewBag.Title };
}
```

Hope this helps. good luck